# API транзакция blockchain

Tags: php, api, blockchain, blockchain.info

нашел в доке такую конструкцию, правильно ли я понимаю, что так можно проверить по хеш данного кошелька, что был осуществлен перевод? И если так, как мне принять эти данные и проверить по хеш?

```
https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address

{
    "hash160":"660d4ef3a743e3e696ad990364e555c271ad504b",
    "address":"1AJbsFZ64EpEfS5UAjAfcUG8pH8Jn3rn1F",
    "n_tx":17,
    "n_unredeemed":2,
    "total_received":1031350000,
    "total_sent":931250000,
    "final_balance":100100000,
    "txs":[--Array of Transactions--]
}
```

Comment: Этого недостаточно. Вам еще нужно проверить количество подтверждений вашей транзакции. Здесь пишут, как это делается: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-confirmations-of-a-transaction-and-its-fee-usi

Answer (score 0):

```
Как я понял, берем эту функцию и получаем по хешу число подтверждений, если 2 то ок иначе false? а как проверить на тот ли адрес кинул человек со своего кошелька? ТО есть, мне нужно проверить, два кошелька участвовали ли в этой транзакции?

function get_tx_confirmation($tx_hash_id){ $raw_lastest_block= json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/latestblock"), true); $lastest_block=$raw_lastest_block["height"];
    $raw_tx=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash_id"), true); 
    $tx_block_height=$raw_tx["block_height"]; 
    $confirmations = $lastest_block - $tx_block_height +1; 
    return $confirmations;
    }
```